# Search elements that contain specific keyord in href and hide other (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make search box for a webpage where a user type a keyword and my code searches that keyword in href of all elements and hide all those elements which do not contain that keyword in their href .

I have tried a JavaScript code that reads text in href and also read text in search box and then checks if text in search box is a substring of a string in href. I have used indexOf function of java Script to check substring

This code Should show those elements which contain keyword in their href and hide those which do not contain this keyword in their href.
Instead nothing is happening.

```js
function MyFunction() {
  var container, value, txtvalue, i, searchtxt, get;
  get = document.getElementById("searchtext");
  searchtxt = get.value.toUpperCase();
  container = document.getElementById("back");
  value = container.getElementByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    txtvalue = value[i].href;
    if (txtvalue.toUpperCase.indexOf(searchtxt) > -1) {
      value.style.display = "";
    } else {
      a.style.display = "none"
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 625px;
}

.linkbox {
  width: 11%;
  height: 34%;
  background-color: green;
  top: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  left: 3.5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 10px -8px black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0; background-color:yellow;">
  <input type="text" id="searchtext" placeholder="search here" />
  <button class="toclick" onclick="MyFunction()"></button>
  <div class="back" id="back">
    <a href="1-spiderman-far-from-home.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images0.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="2-Aladdin-2019.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images1.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="3-venom-2018.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images2.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="4-Alita-battle-angel-2019.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images3.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="5-Antman-and-the-wasp.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images4.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="6-Fantastic-beasts-crime-of-grindelwald-2019.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images5.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: The Javascript section must not have `<script>` or `<script>` in it - Javascript only, not HTML tags, else you get (as you're getting currently) `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: "*Uncaught TypeError: container.getElementByTagName is not a function*" you're missing `s` in `Elements`, it should be `container.getElementsByTagName`

Comment: @sikandar are you still having problems?

Comment: @Carsten-Lovbo-Andersen no i have got solutuin now.

Answer (score 0):

There where a few mistakes in your code.

1. Use `getElementsByTagName` not `getElementByTagName`
2. Use `toUpperCase()` not `toUpperCase`
3. `a.style.display` should be `value[i].style.display`

**Demo**

```js
function MyFunction() {
  var container, value, txtvalue, i, searchtxt, get;
  get = document.getElementById("searchtext");
  searchtxt = get.value.toUpperCase();
  container = document.getElementById("back");
  value = container.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    txtvalue = value[i].href;
    console.log(txtvalue)
    if (txtvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchtxt) > -1) {
      value[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      value[i].style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 625px;
}

.linkbox {
  width: 11%;
  height: 34%;
  background-color: green;
  top: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  left: 3.5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 10px -8px black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0; background-color:yellow;">
  <input type="text" id="searchtext" placeholder="search here" />
  <button class="toclick" onclick="MyFunction()">Search</button>
  <div class="back" id="back">
    <a href="1-spiderman-far-from-home.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images0.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="2-Aladdin-2019.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images1.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="3-venom-2018.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images2.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="4-Alita-battle-angel-2019.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images3.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="5-Antman-and-the-wasp.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images4.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="6-Fantastic-beasts-crime-of-grindelwald-2019.html">
      <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images5.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .back{
        width:100%;
        height:625px;
    }
    .linkbox{
        width:11%;
        height:34%;
        background-color:green;
        top:4%;
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px solid black;
        margin-left:2.5%;
        margin-top:4%;
        left:3.5%;
        box-shadow:0px 20px 10px -8px black;
        border-radius:12px;
    }
    .text{
        width:100%;
        top:50%;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style> 
</head>

<body style="margin:0; background-color:yellow;">
    <input type="text" id="searchtext" placeholder="search here" />
    <button class="toclick" onclick="MyFunction()">Click</button>
    <div class="back" id="back">
        <a href="1-spiderman-far-from-home.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images0.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
                <div class="text"></div></div>
        </a>
        <a href="2-Aladdin-2019.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images1.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;">
                <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="3-venom-2018.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images2.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
                <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="4-Alita-battle-angel-2019.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images3.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
                <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="5-Antman-and-the-wasp.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images4.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
                <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="6-Fantastic-beasts-crime-of-grindelwald-2019.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('images5.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
                <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
        function MyFunction(){
                var  value, txtvalue, i, searchtxt;
                searchtxt=document.getElementById("searchtext").value.toUpperCase();
                value = document.getElementById("back").getElementsByTagName("a");

                for(i=0; i <value.length ; i++){
                    txtvalue = value[i].href.toUpperCase();
                    if(txtvalue.includes(searchtxt))
                    {
                        value[i].style.display="";

                    }
                    else{
                        value[i].style.display="none"
                    }
                }

        }

        </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

okay Try this one, looks cool and its working fine

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .back{
          width:100%;
          height:625px;
      }
      .linkbox{
          width:11%;
          height:34%;
          background-color:green;
          top:4%;
          display:inline-block;
          border:1px solid black;
          margin-left:2.5%;
          margin-top:4%;
          left:3.5%;
          box-shadow:0px 20px 10px -8px black;
          border-radius:12px;
      }
      .text{
          width:100%;
          top:50%;
          position:relative;
          text-align:center;
          font-size:100%;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
  </style> 
  </head>
  
  <body style="margin:0; background-color:yellow;">
      <input type="text" id="searchtext" placeholder="search here" />
      <button class="toclick" onclick="MyFunction()">Click</button>
      <div class="back" id="back">
          <a href="1-spiderman-far-from-home.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bd/Spider-Man_Far_From_Home_poster.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
              <div class="text"></div></div>
          </a>
          <a href="2-Aladdin-2019.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91A0Svq4X0L._SY445_.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;">
              <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="3-venom-2018.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a6/Venom_%28soundtrack%29.jpg/220px-Venom_%28soundtrack%29.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
              <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="4-Alita-battle-angel-2019.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/ee/Alita_Battle_Angel_%282019_poster%29.png/220px-Alita_Battle_Angel_%282019_poster%29.png'); background-size:100% 100%;">
              <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="5-Antman-and-the-wasp.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fmarkhughes%2Ffiles%2F2018%2F06%2FANT-MAN-AND-THE-WASP-new-poster-1200x1777.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
              <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="6-Fantastic-beasts-crime-of-grindelwald-2019.html">
            <div class="linkbox" style="background:url('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjFiMGUzMTAtNDAwMC00ZjRhLTk0OTUtMmJiMzM5ZmVjODQxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDM2NDM2MQ@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%;">
              <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
      </div>
  </body>
  <script>
          function MyFunction(){
            var searchtxt = document.getElementById("searchtext").value;
            var value = document.getElementById("back").getElementsByTagName("a");

            for(i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
              var txtvalue = value[i].href.toUpperCase();
              if(txtvalue.includes(searchtxt.toUpperCase())){
                    value[i].style.display="";
                }
                else{
                  value[i].style.display="none"
                }
            }
          }
  
          </script>
  
  </html>
```